# hyphenation of text

Tags: paragraphs, hyphenation

As you can see in the screenshot, both paragraph's text is just a little bit over the frame. How could I prevent it?

Additional information: `alma` is a hungarian word means `apple`, so it is a very simple word.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage{microtype}

\hyphenation{al-ma}

\begin{document}
\textbf{alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma (30)} \\

\textbf{alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma (30)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you have made a long string  that can only break at `-` with no white space to stretch but then specified a justified paragraph which breaks exactly at the marginn. That is not achievable.  You need to set `\raggedright`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I have anothe question, If I put the `\raggedright` outside the `\being{document}` everything is fine. But if I put it like the following `\textbf{\raggedright alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma (30)}`  it is not working. Is there a proper way to use `\raggedright` only in **one paragraph**?

Comment: I know about `{
\raggedright
\textbf{...}
}` but another way.

Comment: what way do you want? put `\par` before  the `}` but if you just  want a one-off  I would not use `\raggedright` just use `\\ ` at the point you want the line break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encase the paragraph(s) in question in a `sloppypar` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
``fussy'' (normal)

\textbf{alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma (30)} 

\textbf{alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma (30)}

\medskip
``sloppy''

\begin{sloppypar}
\textbf{alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma (30)} 

\textbf{alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma-alma (30)}
\end{sloppypar}

\end{document}
```